# "Couldn't resolve host" when downloading Fedora 16 packages

Tags: fedora, yum

I'm using `yum` to install `make`, I am getting the following error. I tried all solutions from similar questions but the issue remains.

```
http://download.fedoraproject.org/pub/fedora/linux/releases/16/Everything/i386/os/repodata/repomd.xml: [Errno 14] curl#6 - "Couldn't resolve host"
Trying other mirror
```

Answer (score 5):

In your case the main problem is that you're using Fedora 16 which is no longer supported. That means you can't install new software as the main mirrors have been purged of Fedora 16 packages. Check the [Fedora Release Schedule](https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/Releases).

You should have upgraded years ago.

Fedora is evolving quite rapidly and by design releases have short life cycles and are not intended for long term deployment. If you want long term stability deploy CentOS or the LTS Ubuntu releases instead.

---

The edit on your question removed the "Couldn't resolve host" error which normally indicates a problem with your network settings, either the name server configuration in `/etc/resolv.conf` or the complete network configuration.

You can test that with for instance `ping www.google.com` ; if that generates a similar error but `ping 8.8.8.8` does work you need to reconfigure your name servers.